# Javascript - fill in the textbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, textbox

Is it possible to fill textbox using javascript?
I have this code

```
<input type="text" id="output">
```

After using the script, I want to have selected value in textbox. I'm very new to javascript and I tried this

```
javascript: document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "100";
```

However, it doesn't work as I expected. So after using the script I want HTML look like

```
<input type="text" id="output" value="100">
```

Is there any way to manage this? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `.value` or `.setAttribute`.

```
document.getElementById('output').value = "100";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('output').setAttribute("value", "100");
```

Comment: setAttribute is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!